# Visual Studio 2015 crashes on install

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I've been trying to install Visual Studio 2015 Professional but when I open the .exe and Visual Studio logo appears, the installer crashes and reports that "setup detected an issue during the operation". 
I checked the log file to see what is going on and found out that the following section may be causing the problem:

```
[2490:2168][2016-08-25T14:38:58]i000: MUX:  Aquiring mutex 'Global\Devdiv' with a timeout of 0 ms
[2490:2168][2016-08-25T14:38:58]i000: MUX:  Mutex 'Global\Devdiv' ownership: True
[2490:2168][2016-08-25T14:38:58]i000: MUX:  Seen existing cache mutex 'Global\Devdiv CacheMutex': False
[2490:2168][2016-08-25T14:38:58]i000: MUX:  Aquiring mutex 'Global\Devdiv CacheMutex' with a timeout of 60000 ms
[2490:2168][2016-08-25T14:38:58]i000: MUX:  Mutex 'Global\Devdiv CacheMutex' ownership: True
[2490:2168][2016-08-25T14:38:59]e000: MUX:  ERROR: Could not load file or assembly 'PresentationCore, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
[2490:2168][2016-08-25T14:38:59]e000: MUX:  Stack:    at Microsoft.Devdiv.Bootstrapper.ManagedUx.RunUI(ViewModelCommonUi viewModel)
at Microsoft.Devdiv.Bootstrapper.ManagedUx.RunInteractiveUI(ViewModelCommonUi viewModel)
at Microsoft.Devdiv.Bootstrapper.ManagedUx.InternalRun()
at Microsoft.Devdiv.Bootstrapper.ManagedUx.Run()
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
[2490:2168][2016-08-25T14:38:59]i000: MUX:  Metrics: ShouldSendData=True
[2490:2168][2016-08-25T14:38:59]i000: MUX:  Permission to upload: Yes
```

Any idea of what the real problem/cause is ?

Comment: The disk on that machine is pretty corrupted when the installer spits out an error like that.  You can blindly hope that it was only PresentationCore.dll that was banged up but that kind of damage is very rarely isolated.  Don't ignore it.

Comment: Where is the log file located? I got the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

According to the log file, the problem was that .Net framework (3.5) was interfering with the VS2015 installation process. So the main solution was to turn off .Net Frawework 3.5 option in Windows features, restart my PC and then install VS2015. It worked like a charm.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me it was mysql setup
that destroyed the path by adding ^

so edit the path and make sure it does not have any invalid characters.
like ^